# Channel Worker crash: how to do some task before crash?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-channels

For debugging purposes, I need to do a task (send an email) when some Channel Workers stops for an error.

I don't find a closure method that I could edit to add mi task in the SyncConsumer or AsyncConsumer.

channels==2.2.0
channels-redis==2.4.0

Comment: post a block of code with some comments so we can see what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a completely generic approach:

You can try overriding the Consumers `__call__` method

```python
async def __call__(self, receive, send):

     try: 
         await super().__call__(receive, send):
     except:
         .... do your stuff
         raise
```

Comment: Ty bro! It could help